# Building an XMERL document in Erlang

Tags: xml, erlang

Can anyone show me how to build a simple XML document using XMERL? The documentation only shows how to append to a current XML document that is read from a file. I want to create a new XML document from scratch.

For example, I want to write a simple structure like this out to an XML file:

```
Data = {myNode,[{foo,"Foo"},{bar,"Bar"}]}.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

xmerl's "simple" format is similar to yours: (note the third value, a list of child elements)

```
Data = {myNode,[{foo,"Foo"},{bar,"Bar"}], []}.
```

This can be "exported" into XML to use as a string:

```
> lists:flatten(xmerl:export_simple([Data], xmerl_xml)).
"<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><myNode foo=\"Foo\" bar=\"Bar\"/>"
```

Or written to a file:

```
> file:write_file("/tmp/foo.xml", xmerl:export_simple([Data2], xmerl_xml)).
ok
```

Note that export_simple takes a list of elements, not a single root element.  Also, depending on what you do with the result, flattening might be unnecessary.

Comment: I was missing the list of child elements.  Thank you!